# Creating Notebook Failed - An error ocurred while creating a new notebook GOOGLE CLOUD DATALAB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

In GCP. According to this Article, https://mohameddhaoui.github.io/dataengineering/chatbot3/
I created a new google cloud datalab instance, and run it on port 8081. When I go to Google Cloud Datalab and click on **add note**, the following error is presented.

[Datalab Error PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IufIL.png)

I am the owner of the account and have full access to the resources.

This is the command I used to deploy the datalab instance:

**datalab create datalab-instance**

The result of the execution is as follows.

This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
ssh: connect to host 35.229.109.170 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Connection closed
Attempting to reconnect...
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/myuserXXX/.ssh/google_compute_engine':

The connection to Datalab **is now open and will remain until this command is killed.**
Click on the *Web Preview* (square button at top-right), select *Change port > Port **8081***, and start using Datalab.

Your help will be very appreciated.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you use your local terminal or Google Shell to create your datalab instance? Also, have you considered using **AI Platform Notebooks** instead? The pricing is quite similar as Datalab, [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/pricing).